# Solr child document update breaks parent non-stored field

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr8

I'm using Solr 8.11. I have one field in my Solr schema that is indexed but not stored (`indexed=true stored=false`). When I update another field in a Solr doc, the information in the non-stored field is lost (it is not searchable anymore). One solution would be to reindex the Solr document, but in my case, it is not possible.

I tried to solve the issue by creating a child document that contains the field that is updated. However, that field should also be indexed, so to my understanding, in-place update is unavailable. On the other hand, the atomic update on the child doc also messes up the non-stored parent document field.

What are my options, is this doable at all with parent-child solution?
One option might be to split the documents entirely (one would contain the non-stored field, the other one the field that gets updated). Then I could maybe use Join Query to "combine" the data. However, this is extra hassle.
Are there any better options?